# What are the new rules for when a KT1 gets destroyed? Or when "--burn-cap" must be used to send funds to a tz1/tz2/tz3 account?

Tags: contract

What are the new rules for when a KT1 gets destroyed? Is there a certain balance that it goes below?

What about tz1/tz2/tz3?  I noticed that sometimes `--burn-cap` must be used to send funds. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of 003_PsddFKi3:

An originated account is forever.<sup>[[1](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_storage.ml#L461)]</sup>

An implicit account is 'allocated'<sup>[[2](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_storage.ml#L486)]</sup> and 'deleted'<sup>[[3](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_storage.ml#L470)]</sup> as its balance goes above and back to zero (if it is not a delegate<sup>[[4](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/contract_storage.ml#L465)]</sup>).

Currently you must pay a storage burn to allocate an implicit account, and there is no refund upon deletion. The `storage_limit` for an operation accounts for this burn (along with the origination burn for KT1's, and storage growth for scripts).<sup>[[5](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/apply.ml#L383)]</sup><sup>[[6](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/fees_storage.ml#L61)]</sup><sup>[[7](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_protocol/src/fees_storage.ml#L82)]</sup>

The `--burn-cap` tells the client how high (in tez) you are willing to set the `storage_limit` (in bytes). You must provide it any time the `storage_limit` will be positive, to confirm you are willing to burn the tez.<sup>[[8](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/366f64f3df266cf02a06412d6760f73626d0a2bf/src/proto_003_PsddFKi3/lib_client/injection.ml#L491)]</sup>

Comment: I was amazed by the superscript links and wondered how you did until i see you actually took the pain to type the sup html tags :) there should be an easier way to do that! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that an address gets ever destroyed. You have to burn XTZ in order to create an address.

Comment: I do recall that used to be the case that contracts would be disappeared completely if the balance ever go too low, but that implicit accounts didnt suffer this.  and now, it seems I cannot drain a KT1 such that it disappears.  and also, it seems that in some cases is costs extra `--burn-cap` to transfer to an implicit account?